# Multiple setups for a mockset ASP.net only carries out 1 mock

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, moq

So my problem is that I've got to mock two things. One is a method that finds a person and the other is a list of those people over which it iterates. However it doesn't get both setups but only 1. I've tried putting them in different orders and each time only the top 1 works.

here's my code:

```
Person test = new Person()
            {
                City = "Eindhoven Area, Netherlands.",
                userid = 1,
                ID = 1,
                Email = "fraylight@gmail.com",
                ExtraInfo = "blabla",
                HobbyProjectICTRelated = "a",
                Hobbys = "",
                LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills = "Java:7, C#:4, Software Documentation:4, Software Development:4, HTML:2, CSS:2, jQuery:1",
                Name = "Marijn van Donkelaar",
                PhoneNr = "0612345678",
                ProfileImage = "/Images/hollemar.jpg",
                SkillsToLearn = "ASP.net:2, JAVA:3",
                Stand = "",
                Summary = "",
                YearsOfWorkExperience = 6,
                PeopleManagerApproved = true,
                PeopleManager = "Richard"
            };
            Person test1 = new Person()
            {
                City = "Eindhoven Area, Netherlands.",
                userid = 2,
                ID = 2,
                Email = "fraylight@gmail.com",
                ExtraInfo = "",
                HobbyProjectICTRelated = "a",
                Hobbys = "zwemmen",
                LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills = "Java:8, C#:4, Software Documentation:4, Software Development:4, HTML:2, CSS:2, jQuery:1",
                Name = "Richard Holleman",
                PhoneNr = "",
                ProfileImage = "/Images/hollemar.jpg",
                SkillsToLearn = "ASP.net:2, JAVA:2",
                Stand = "",
                Summary = "",
                YearsOfWorkExperience = 16,
                PeopleManagerApproved = true,
                PeopleManager = "Richard"
            };
            Person test2 = new Person()
            {
                City = "Eindhoven Area, Netherlands.",
                userid = 3,
                ID = 3,
                Email = "fraylight@gmail.com",
                ExtraInfo = "",
                HobbyProjectICTRelated = "",
                Hobbys = "zwemmen",
                LearntSkillsAndLevelOfSkills = "C#:4, SQL:4, PLSQL:4, HTML:2, CSS:2, jQuery:1",
                Name = "Jasmine Test",
                PhoneNr = "0612345678",
                ProfileImage = "/Images/hollemar.jpg",
                SkillsToLearn = "ASP.net:2, JAVA:1",
                Stand = "",
                Summary = "",
                YearsOfWorkExperience = 11,
                PeopleManagerApproved = true,
                PeopleManager = "Richard"
            };
            var data = new List<Person> { test, test1, test2 }.AsQueryable();

            var dbSetMock = new Mock<IDbSet<Person>>();
            dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
            dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());

            var mockContext = new Mock<PersonDBContext>();
            mockContext.Setup(x => x.Persons).Returns(dbSetMock.Object);
            mockContext.Setup(x => x.Persons.Find(1)).Returns(test);

            var service = new PersonController(mockContext.Object);

            var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            controllerContext.Setup(t => t.HttpContext.Session["loggedinuser"]).Returns(10);

            service.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;

            ViewResult detailspageresultcorrect = (ViewResult) service.Details(10);

            Person resultpersoncorrect = (Person) detailspageresultcorrect.Model;

            Assert.IsTrue(resultpersoncorrect.Name.Equals(test.Name));
```

The part where it goes wrong is on the line of: var mockContext = new Mock();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to mock the `Find` method directed on the `IDbSet` instead of going via the Persons property.

So your setups would look like the following:

```
var dbSetMock = new Mock<IDbSet<Person>>();
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());

dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Find(1)).Returns(test);

var mockContext = new Mock<PersonDBContext>();
mockContext.Setup(x => x.Persons).Returns(dbSetMock.Object);
```

Comment: nope not possible... but that's because the x is a DbContext class and within that class you keep your DbSet am i correct?

Comment: The find method is defined on the [IDbContext<T> interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679596%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) so you should mock it on your dbSetMock

Comment: Yep, otherwise the Setup for the Persons.Find method implicitly overwrites your original Persons setup.